# I am trying to write a prolog program for fibbonaci series.This code is going in infinite loop .Can someone tell what's the error?

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop, fibonacci, failure-slice

```
fib(0,0).   
fib(1,1).  
fib(A,Result):-    
    fib(A-1,R),  
    fib(A-2,P),  
    Result is R+P.
```

Comment: Your program does not stop. Consider performing a Cut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why, first narrow down the reason for non-termination. Here is the smallest part of your program that still loops:

```
fib(0,0) :- false.
fib(1,1) :- false.
fib(A,Result):-    
    fib(A-1,R), false,
    fib(A-2,P),  
    Result is R+P.
```

No matter what the arguments are, this program will loop. And thus your original program will loop too.

To fix this you need to change something in the visible part: You need to ensure that `A > 1`. In this manner the program now terminates.

Further, as noted correctly by @andsanmar, `A-1` alone is not a number, but just the term `-(A,1)` so it can never be `0` nor `1`.  So either write

```
fib(N,0) :- N =:= 0.
fib(N,1) :- N =:= 1.
...
```

Or add `(is)/2` as suggested by @andsanmar.

For more on how to narrow down reasons for non-termination see [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice).

Answer (score 0):

When you do `fib(A-1,R)`, being A=4, for example, what's going to be sent is 4-1 instead of 3, you need to do `Aminus1 is A -1, fib(Aminus1,R)`. The same with the A-2

Comment: Please note that fib(0,1) still loops